# How to upload Pending Attachment to Yammer

Tags: httpwebrequest, webclient, yammer

I'm trying to upload files to yammer via REST Api.

the API say ,i could use

**`POST https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json`**

**`attachmentn and pending_attachmentn - Yammer provides two methods to associate attachments with a message. Both make use of multi-part HTTP upload (see RFC1867).`**

then i try to post my message via WebRequest.like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

but unfortunately,  i got "Internal Server Error"[500]. like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823955/yammer-api-attachments-upload)

is anyone could tell me ,how to upload a file to yammer?

and , how to get a pending_attachment list?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally , I know the reason for the failure .
**request format.**

[RFC 1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867)say:

```
    Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x

    --AaB03x
    content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"

    Joe Blow
    --AaB03x
    content-disposition: form-data; name="pics"; filename="file1.txt"
    Content-Type: text/plain

     ... contents of file1.txt ...
    --AaB03x--
```

there two points

1. **multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x** ->
   **multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x**
2. no empty line at first line

> ```
> Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
> --AaB03x
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"
>
> Joe Blow
> --AaB03x
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pics"; filename="file1.txt"
> Content-Type: text/plain
>
> ... contents of file1.txt ...
> --AaB03x--
> ```

Comment: Hi @geminiyellow, I'm trying to upload a file to yammer as well and receiving a whole spectrum of errors. I remember one of these approaches also made me face 500 server error so if you can explain what were your finding in a little more simpler terms, it will be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: @S4nd33p sorry, that question was posted 3 years ago, i dont use yammer now. hope anybody can help you .

Comment: At least you responded. Thank you, i'll keep looking. :)

Answer (score 0):

I stuck for days just to post message with attachment. I have no idea how to post message with attachmentN, but it is working with pending_attachmentN method.

First you have to call pending_attachment API and get the result ID. Then assign the ID into pending_attachmentN on message API.

I refer to [sample](https://github.com/MikeWasson/HttpClientSample/blob/master/src/HttpClientSample/Program.cs) as my baseline code. Then I merged with this [C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload)

Find below code to post message with attachment to Yammer. Hope can save your days.

```
    public static async Task<PendingAttachment> Upload(string FilePath)
    {
        byte[] byteFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FilePath);

        PendingAttachment pa = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + token);
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("Upload----" + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
            {
                content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(byteFile)), "attachment", fi.Name);

                using (var message = await client.PostAsync("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/pending_attachments", content))
                {
                    if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        pa = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PendingAttachment>(result);
                        return pa;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    var FilePath = @"D:\Workspace\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.docx";
    var pa = await Upload(FilePath);

    MessageParam message = new MessageParam()
    {
            body = "posting attachment",
            group_id = XXXXXXX,
            pending_attachment1 = pa.id
    };
    var result = await CreateMessageAsync(message);
```

PendingAttachment Class and its property class

```
    public class PendingAttachment
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int network_id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string web_url { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string original_name { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string content_type { get; set; }
        public string content_class { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public int owner_id { get; set; }
        public bool official { get; set; }
        public string small_icon_url { get; set; }
        public string large_icon_url { get; set; }
        public string download_url { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public string preview_url { get; set; }
        public string large_preview_url { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string owner_type { get; set; }
        public string last_uploaded_at { get; set; }
        public int last_uploaded_by_id { get; set; }
        public string last_uploaded_by_type { get; set; }
        public object uuid { get; set; }
        public object transcoded { get; set; }
        public object streaming_url { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public int y_id { get; set; }
        public string overlay_url { get; set; }
        public string privacy { get; set; }
        public object group_id { get; set; }
        public bool is_pending { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public string scaled_url { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public int latest_version_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Latest_Version latest_version { get; set; }
        public Stats stats { get; set; }
        public string _OriginalFileName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Latest_Version
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int file_id { get; set; }
        public string content_type { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public int uploader_id { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string download_url { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public string preview_url { get; set; }
        public string large_preview_url { get; set; }
        public string post_processed_id { get; set; }
        public object streaming_url { get; set; }
        public string revert_url { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public string scaled_url { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail_path { get; set; }
        public string preview_path { get; set; }
        public string large_preview_path { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
    public class Stats
    {
        public int following { get; set; }
        public int followers { get; set; }
        public int updates { get; set; }
        public object first_reply_id { get; set; }
        public object first_reply_at { get; set; }
        public int latest_reply_id { get; set; }
        public string latest_reply_at { get; set; }
        public int shares { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How did you decipher the return type of the PendingAttachment API call?
Can you please share the format?

Comment: @SauravSircar you can read it from the return of ReadAsStringAsync() method. It will be a json string. Then, you need to decode it, as it contains some escape character. Last, on Visual Studio, open Edit Menu -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes. Voila! you just created the class of the Json string and can be used to deserialize into object. anyway I will update my post to include the PendingAttachment class

Comment: Thank you @Eric!
I also wanted to ask, what does the line `pa = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PendingAttachment>(result);` do, and how can I include it into my project?
I need the output to be proper, so I need that line to work properly. I'm just using Visual Studio to make an extension for another application.

Comment: its doing deserialize object from string into an object. Im using Newtonshoft 3rd party library, you can add this into your project via Manage Nuget Package.